# How do I update the CSV file after running my code in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a movie theatre booking system as part of a school project so my knowledge about python is fairly limited.

I have the following code to import the csv file, which stores the status of the seats (0 = not booked and 1 = booked)

```
import csv

with open('seats.csv', newline='') as csvfile:

    seats = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

Here's my code for booking the seat:

```
def bookSeat():
  print("Booking a Seat by Row/Column")
  booked = False
  while booked == False:
    row = int(input("Enter a row number (between 0 and 5)"))
    column = int(input("Enter a column number (between 0 and 7)"))
 
    if seats[row][column]==1:
      print("This seat is already booked.")
    else:
      print("This seat is empty.")
      print("Booking seat...")
      seats[row][column]=1
      print("We have now booked this seat for you.")
      booked=True
```

**So my question is after booking a seat (replacing the 0 with a 1), how do I update the csv file to reflect this change?**

Thanks for all your help in advance!!

Comment: Try using `csv.writer`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer does this overwrite the previously written data or create a new csv file?

Comment: Depends what you pass into `open()` function

Comment: You can also write to a CSV file using a writer object and the **.write_row()** method

Comment: @OneCricketeer So what would I need to do if I want to overwrite the original csv file?

Answer (score 2):

This can be acheived using `csv.writer()` object which has the `writerows` property.

```
def bookSeat():

    print("Booking a Seat by Row/Column")
    booked = False
    while booked == False:

        row = int(input("Enter a row number (between 0 and 5)"))
        column = int(input("Enter a column number (between 0 and 7)"))

        if seats[row][column]==1:
            print("This seat is already booked.")
        else:
            print("This seat is empty.")
        print("Booking seat...")
        seats[row][column]=1
        print("We have now booked this seat for you.")
        booked=True

    # Rewrite the CSV with the new list of seats
    writer = csv.writer(open('seats.csv', 'w'))
    writer.writerows(seats)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

If you want you can also do this with pandas df: (it will simply overwirite it every time)

```
import pandas as pd

seats = pd.read_csv('seats.csv', sep=',')

def bookSeat():
    print("Booking a Seat by Row/Column")
    booked = False
    while booked == False:
        row = 'row ' + input("Enter a row number (between 0 and 5)")
        column = int(input("Enter a column number (between 0 and 7)"))

      if seats[row][column]==1:
          print("This seat is already booked.")
      else:
          print("This seat is empty.")
          print("Booking seat...")
          seats[row][column]=1
          print("We have now booked this seat for you.")
          booked=True
bookSeat()

seats.to_csv('seats.csv', sep=',')`
```

note: i put a 'row ' + input in the row variable, so your csv should look like this:

row 0,row 1,row 2,row 3,row 4,row 5

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0

this will create a better overview over the occupied rows!

Good luck with your code!